# 99% vs 1% in terms of code compilation or build

Tags: java, netbeans-7

This is in terms of code compilation and nothing else.. :)

So, I am a newbie in my company and predictably got stuck with an awesomely slow computer. And I am having a big problem with my Netbeans running out of memory/resource every time I make a build. I am compiling my JAVA files.

I was using 7.0, and even though I was getting this error, I got by it by compiling the source packages in chunks. (sometimes I had to compile the selected ones more than once)

But ever since I moved to 7.2, this problem is getting worse. I have to now compile the packages in even more smaller chunks. Sometimes package by package and file by file. Hence costing me a lot of time and even lot of hair.

I have no idea which packages to compile first. The netbeans was taking care of that. Therefore, taking resources.

Most of my colleagues have powerful computers and have no problem building the whole source base. So, I started getting the complied packages and only building the required ones.

So, is this the correct approach or building the whole source (even though I just make changes to 1% of the total code base, at any given time)?

Almost everyone in this company is building the whole code base, at least once, even though most of the changes are only in 1%.

Comment: Yes, all the code. You won't know how the code is optimized during compilation by the compiler. If you compile only files it may not show its effect to the other compiles class files. The best thing you can do is to request a better computer

Comment: CPU cycles are always cheaper than people cycles (Book: continuous integration).

I had a similar issue and simply convinced the manager to order me a new machine. It was not easy, but ever since i don't feel like drinking :)

Comment: If you are unable to feasibly build the entire project you need to speak to your manager about upgrading or replacing your computer.

Answer (score 2):

It is *far better* to build the entire project and have it work as designed, then build 99% of it and it doesn't work.  There's no indication that the 1% is critical or non-critical code, and as a beginner, you can't tell that just right off the bat.

I would inform your teammates/IT personnel about the slow build and ask what can be done to resolve it, instead of building the code in chunks.

Comment: We have weekly builds, where the whole code base is built and store in a repository. I am getting the class files of those parts that I don't need to touch and source files for those that I need to. So, in this case, is building the whole project the right course? In effect I am getting the whole project as a whole but only compiling some source files and adding the others.

Comment: The weekly builds are more of a stable build regimen than say, a mainline build (trunk).  Your code base repository should build against the mainline.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should highlight the issues with a developer having a slow machine impeding the work you are doing, when you explain the difference in lost productivity versus hardware cost, you will shortly have a new machine.

Then you can stop worrying about building "99%" and get on to real issues.

Comment: I am not building the 99%. I am just building the 1% and getting the rest as compiled files. When I build 100%, I am running out of memory.

Comment: That was my point, you should be able to build the 99% you are not building and not run out of memory or have it take a long time to do.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is this the correct approach or building the whole source (even
>   though I just make changes to 1% of the total code base, at any given
>   time)?

I think that you can build only some parts of project only if you perfectly know all internal dependencies and can guaranty that no unexpected behaviour in nearby module happens after your modifications were made. It is my opinion. Moreover, you can change code and compile it succesful, but the entire project build can fail the same.

**P.S.** You should get company to buy you a new computer.

Comment: Hmm.. But I am adding the other 99% as compiled files and only building the 1%. Yup, I know the dependencies of the part that I am touching. Therefore, I was wondering if I needed to build the entire source code.

Comment: If there is something dependent on module you have changed then you better recompile it too (at least recompile, but it will be much better to perform some available testing procedures too). In my post I just wanted to say, that usually projects have a lot of different modules with very large number of dependencies which lead to conclusion that it is always better to recompile everything (and test). Human brain can not always remember all dependencies and can not analyse every change. It is much better to compile and test and save a lot of time which can be spent on wtf investigation.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to build the entire project. Try tune `netbeans.conf`

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss4m -J-Xms128m -J-XX:PermSize=128m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true-J-XX:+UseParNewGC -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

Comment: I did that. increased Xmx to 512m and then to 1024m. Still getting the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could walk through all dependencies and make yourself a dependency hierarchy map, and you should only have to compile the code you've changed plus everything that depends on it. However it's not necessarily 100% foolproof and requires A LOT of effort for very little gain. It's not something that I would expect to be a newbies responsibility to sort out, rather your superiors should get you sorted out with some appropriate kit.